# React Native Firebase Ref() and Navigation complication

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I am using firebase along with React navigation for this app.

For a component of mine, I am able to retrieve data from my firebase realtime database to populate an array of components. This is done in my componentDidMount() function.

If, however, I navigate to another page, and then navigate back (the goBack() function is not manually called), no items are rendered. By using console logs I was able to figure out the following:

-componentDidMount() IS being called again when I revisit the page.

-I am able to enter into the function specified under:

```
Ref.on('value', (snap) => { .... });
```

as I am able to call console logs from within there.

-states are reset back to what the constructor assigns, as loading is set to true again.

It seems like I am simply unable to retrieve data from firebase after I call the ref() the first time. The following is the important aspects of my code.

```
export default class RestaurantPage extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    showSearch:false,
    loading:true,
    index:0,
    data: []
  }
  this.rootRef = firebaseApp.database().ref();
  this.cards = [];
}

componentDidMount(){
var Ref = firebaseApp.database().ref("Restaurants");
Ref.on('value', (snap) => {
  var restaurants = snap.val();
  this.setState({data: Object.keys(restaurants)});
  console.log(this.state.data);
  var day = moment().format('dddd');
  for(var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++){
    var newSnap = snap.child(this.state.data[i]);

    var id = newSnap.val()
    var name = newSnap.child('Name').val();
    var cuisine = newSnap.child('Cuisine').val();
    var price = newSnap.child('Price').val();
    var address = newSnap.child('Address').val();
    var closing = newSnap.child('Closing/' + day).val();
    var description = newSnap.child('Description').val();
    this.cards.push(
    <RestaurantCard key = {i}
                    id = {id}
                    title = {name}
                    cost = {price}
                    cuisine = {cuisine}
                    tags = {756}
                    closing ={closing}
                    distance = {address}
                    description = {description}/>);
  }
  this.setState({loading:false});
});
}


renderCards = () => {
 console.log("rendercards called");
 return(
   {this.cards}
 );
 }
```

Does anyone have insight on this?

Side Note: No problems occur if I simply am going to another page and then use the goBack() function, as I believe all states are retained anyway in that case.
Additionally: I am using this.props.navigation.navigate(), rather than push().

ALSO: Something that might be quite significant: The issue occurs when I navigate from one page (Feed) to the page I am having issues with (RestaurantPage). Then, I navigate back to (Feed) using my navBar, and then navigate back to (RestaurantPage), at which point I see that the firebase ref() is not working.

Stack Navigator:

```
export default createStackNavigator(
  {
    RestaurantProfile: RestaurantProfile,
    RestaurantPage: RestaurantPage,
    SearchPage: SearchPage,
    SearchResults: SearchResults,
    Feed: Feed,
    OtherUserProfile: OtherUserProfile,
    OtherUserTags: OtherUserTags,
    PersonalTags: PersonalTags
  },
  {
    headerMode:'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Feed',
    transitionConfig: () => ({ screenInterpolator: () => null })
  },
);
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for your stack navigator? And why aren't you using goBack() if you want to retain the states.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to retain the states. On going back to the original page it would be fine if the states had to be reloaded in, as things might always be changing in the back end. I've included the stack navigator in the original post.

Comment: If you are able to enter into the function under  `Ref.on('value', (snap) => { .... });` and still not able to retrieve data then what is the output of `console.log(this.state.data)`, in my opinion the output should be `[]` in both cases because `this.setState()` is asynchronous, IMHO you should try `this.setState({foo:bar},()=>console.log("this.state.foo"))` and then see the output in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not call off() on the firebase ref after calling on()!

The solution is to call Ref.off() in componentDidUnmount or simply use a Ref.once() function rather than Ref.on()